# How to convert attributes with number values to text values using Case/If function in MicroStrategy Visual Insights?

Tags: if-statement, case, custom-data-attribute, microstrategy

I have 2 reports/data sets to create a dashboard in Visual Insight. One data set is from Teradata (directly connected to MicroStrategy). The other data set is from Google BigQuery (connected to MicroStrategy via Intelligent Cube connector). The key of these 2 data sets is Categories.

The problem is the Categories attribute in Teradata is in number values i.e. 55, 45, 14, 29, 30 etc. And the values of Categories from the BQ data set is text i.e Food, Fashion. Food consists of numbers 55, 45 & 14. Numbers 29 & 30 make up Fashion. I tried grouping the number as text in the corresponding naming but the new grouped Teradata attribute doesn't link properly with the other data set.

So my challenge is how to align these 2 data sets with the key attribute and link them properly. I'm thinking of creating new attribute using Case/If function but didn't figure it out. Any other suggestion would also be very much appreciated!

Thank you very much, 
Willow

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new table or a view in MicroStrategy holding both CategoryDESC and CategoryID
where you will have the following

```
Teradata 
Column1          
55
45
14
29
30

BigQuery 
Column1          
Food
Fashion

New table 
Column1          Column2 
Food               55
Food               45
Food               14
Fashion            29
Fashion            30
```